# Nothing is printed

Tags: c

so this is the logic that came to my mind while trying to think of a procedure to convert 
a binary number into  a decimal number. I cannot seem to figure out what's wrong with the program which is preventing it from showing any kind of output at all.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n,temp,r,rev,i, ct;
    rev=0;
    printf("Enter a number in base 10");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    // n is the decimal number
    temp=n;
    while(temp>0)
    {
        r=temp%2;

        if (r==1)
            break;
        else
            ct++;
         temp/=2;
        // ct will count the number of zeros from the top
    }
    while(temp>0)
    {
        r=temp%2;
        rev=(rev*10 + r);
    }
    printf("%d", rev);

    for(i=0;i<ct;i++)
    {
        printf("%i", 0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sit with a pen and paper, assume that the input is a small number (say `n=4`) and see what your program does.  Good luck!

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? What's it doing when you step through the code?

Comment: Need to flush stdout?

Comment: You have *undefined behavior* in your code: You declare the variable `ct` but you never initialize it. That means its value is *indeterminate* (and will be seemingly random). Using an uninitialized local variable leads to this undefined behavior. Until you fix this undefined behavior, your program is incorrect even if there are no compiler errors. If you build with more warning enabled you would have caught this easily, as warnings often indicate "weird" things that might lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: And you will never get out of the second while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has multiple problems:

1) `ct` is an uninitialized variable. Initialize it to 0.

2) The part that calculates the binary in single loop, needs `temp=temp/2` to calculate the next digit in binary.

```
while(temp>0)
{
    r=temp%2;
    rev=(rev*10 + r);
    temp/=2;   // You need this
}
```

3) Your program can handle only a very small set of integers as you represent the binary number using an integer variable (`rev`). And you'll run into the integer overflows even when inputting small numbers such as 2047 (depending on whether the LSB of the binary is 1 and `INT_MAX` on your platform).